# Bootstrap Navbar Links not coloring properly

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

So I'm using a Bootstrap Navbar for a website I'm making and when I try to change the color of the links, it only changes one.

I have already tried using different class names and removing unnecessary classes.

HTML:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="landingPage">Cottrell Pier Association</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link colorMe" href="aboutUs">About Us<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item colorMe">
        <a class="nav-link" href="members-login">Members</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item colorMe">
        <a class="nav-link" href="lifeguard-login">Lifeguards</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```css
.colorMe{
    color:darkgreen !important;
}
```

When I try and do this, the one link that changes is the one that says "About Us". Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.colorMe` class exists on the link for About Us, but on the list item parent of the other two. Just move that class from the list item to the link and it works.

**[Bootply example](https://www.bootply.com/LNo4lJzSTq)**

The reason it doesn't work while only on the list item parent is because Bootstrap already has a more specific selector, `.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link`, that overrides your CSS.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you put classes to `<li>` element instead of `<a>`. Hope it helps.

```css
.colorMe{
    color:darkgreen !important;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="landingPage">Cottrell Pier Association</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link colorMe" href="aboutUs">About Us<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item ">
        <a class="nav-link colorMe" href="members-login">Members</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item ">
        <a class="nav-link colorMe" href="lifeguard-login">Lifeguards</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

update the class `colorMe` to `a` element instead of `li`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="landingPage">Cottrell Pier Association</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link colorMe" href="aboutUs">About Us<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link colorMe" href="members-login">Members</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link colorMe" href="lifeguard-login">Lifeguards</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```